# Как сохранить данные переменных в python?

Tags: python, переменные

Написал небольшую игру-кликер на python (tkinter), и мне нужно чтобы когда человек выходил из игры, и обратно заходил, весь его прогресс сохранялся. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: `pickle` например, объектов в файл, а потом обратно прочитать им же. ну или сами состояние пишите в `json` и потом восстанавливайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть библиотека  sqlite3
Примеры сохранение, обновление данных.

```
import sqlite3
 
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db") # или :memory: чтобы сохранить в RAM
cursor = conn.cursor()
 
# Создание таблицы
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE score_table
                  (score TEXT)
               """)
#только первый раз для создание переменной в таблице, можно использовать при регистрации в формате логин, пароль, 0(очки)
score = 1000
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES (?)", (score)) 

#обновление очков
cusrsor.execute(f"UPDATE score_table SET score = '{score}'")
```

А так советую почитать про библиотеку sqlite3, оставляю ссылку на сайт где можно с ней ознакомиться
https://python-scripts.com/sqlite