# Как сохранить данные программы на python?

Tags: python, tkinter, переменные

Начал писать небольшую игру-кликер на python (tkinter), и мне нужно чтобы когда человек выходил из игры, и обратно заходил, весь его прогресс сохранялся. Как это можно осуществить? Вот исходник:

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import time
w1 = Tk()

w1.resizable(width=False, height=False)
w1.geometry('1250x300')
w1.config(bg='black')
w1.title('KLICKKA')


counter=int(0)
##команды

def k_button():
    global counter
    counter=int(counter+1)
    balance["text"] = ("Баланс:", counter)
    
##Сценарий

balance=Label( text = ("Баланс:", counter), font = 'Consolas 20',
       fg = "green",
       bg = 'black')


k=Button(text='КЛИК!!!!', font = 'Comfortaa 20',
         fg='green',
         bg='gray',
         relief='solid',
         justify='center',
         width='40',
         command=k_button)

#pack
balance.pack()
k.pack()



w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сохранить данные переменных в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174963/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: json, pickle, sqlite3, db etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку сейчас у вас всего один параметр `counter` меняется в процессе работы программы, то вы можете просто сохранить его значение либо в текстовый файл и потом строку из файла распарсить как int обратно. Либо прямо в двоичный файл записать и потом считать.

Но лучше приучаться писать данные в `json` файл, туда сразу структуры можно записывать.

При запуске программы читаете данные из файла. А после каждого изменения состояния программы - записываете данные в файл.